# How can I add space to text in Excel for full fill text length?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How can I add space to text in Excel(2010) for full fill text length.
example
In Excel sheet have 3 column A is length, B is actual text and D is expected text.

(B)text is `ABVC` but require text length is (A)6
then (D)text should be "  ABVC"(<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>ABVC) add space in font of old text to full fill length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `A1=6` and `B1=ABVC` you can insert the following formula in D1:

```
=IF(LEN(B1)<A1,REPT(" ",A1-LEN(B1)),"")&B1
```

Note: I have added a check to make sure B1 is not more than 6 characters, if it is, I use it as is. You could truncate it with the `LEFT` function.

Comment: @Gimp, another use I've found, is to show a progress indicator in a cell (there's probably another way with excel 2010): `=REPT("|",n)` where n varies from 0 to 20 and updates in real time. Good if you want to show off ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately my job is primarily to automate data pulls from databases and applications / clients into final versions of the reports by using VBA / Engineering a reporting-database-solution. ~ so progress bars are not super useful for me. Great idea though. :]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add make cell of 10 characters, then you can use this formula in excel

> =RIGHT("          "&E2,10)

In this formula I had added 10 spaces in between

> ""

marks and concatenate with the cell and after comma (,) i had specified the intended number of characters I want in that cell after execution of this formula. (space not shown in formula)